# Redux: Call the same api but dispatch different actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently I have a redux actions which is `getUsers()` to get all users.

```
export function getUsers (params) {
    return async dispatch => { 
        await dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_REQUEST' });

        const urlParams = params ? new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(params)) : null;

        return axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Environment.GET_USERS+ `?${urlParams}`,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        }).then (async res => {
            await dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS', allUsers: res.data.Data });
        }).catch (err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_FAILURE', error: err.toString() });
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the same `getUsers()` but with param id (eg. `getUsers({ UserId: 'jamesbond007' })`),
and in the action I want to `dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS', user: res.data.Data })`

How can I dispatch different actions with the same api call? Should I duplicate the same code but change the action dispatch? If doing so it becomes repetitive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found way to do this. I declare variables `REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE` and check if the param object contains `UserId`. If yes, it will dispatch `GET_USER_BY_ID` instead of `GET_USERS`.

```
export function getUsers (params) {
    let REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE;

    if (!_.isEmpty(params) && params.UserId) {
        REQUEST = 'GET_USER_BY_ID_REQUEST';
        SUCCESS = 'GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS';
        FAILURE = 'GET_USER_BY_ID_FAILURE';
    } else {
        REQUEST = 'GET_USERS_REQUEST';
        SUCCESS = 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS';
        FAILURE = 'GET_USERS_FAILURE';
    }

    return async dispatch => { 
        await dispatch({ type: REQUEST });

        const urlParams = params ? new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(params)) : null;

        return axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Environment.GET_USERS+ `?${urlParams}`,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        }).then (async res => {
            await dispatch({ type: SUCCESS, payload: res.data.Data });
        }).catch (err => {
            dispatch({ type: FAILURE, error: err.toString() });
        });
    }
}
```

Note that in my reducer, I use only `action.payload`. Eg:

```
case 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS':
    return { ...state, isFetching: false, userList: action.payload };

case 'GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS':
    return { ...state, isFetching: false, user: action.payload };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decide the action by param id, like

```
// all users, paramId is null
// a user, paramId is xxxx
const action = paramId ?
     { type: 'GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS', user: res.data.Data } :
     { type: 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS', allUsers: res.data.Data };
dispatch(action);
```

But, I think your idea is not good. It is better to do the logic in 2 methods. It is readable.